# Value not set to registry using regedit

Tags: node.js, regedit

I am using regedit(npm package) to set a key and value in registry. I have shown my registry window below and also the code to set registry
[![pic][2]][2]

```
function setRegistryValue(){

 regedit.putValue({
        'HKLM\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment': {
           'XYZ': {
                value: '1',
                type: 'REG_SZ'
            },
           'Version': { }
        }
    }, function(err) {app.console.log(err);});

}
``


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH5rz.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQa8h.png
```

Comment: I suspect it is because of  permission

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Iamge didn't get added in the question, but here is the answer for my question.

I observed the architecture inside registry and edited the regedit.putValue as follows, it works!!!

```
function setRegistryValue(){

 regedit.putValue({
        'HKLM\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment': {
           'XYZ': {
                value: '1',
                type: 'REG_SZ'
            }

        }
    }, function(err) {app.console.log(err);});

}
```